# How to redirect a user to the Passwords menu of the Mac Settings app?

Tags: swift, macos

I have a button, that once selected, should redirect the user to the Mac Settings App, and select the 'Passwords' tab, where the user can then login. I am using the following code, however when selected it always just goes to the "Privacy and Security" tab instead. How can I fix this so it redirects to the 'Passwords' tab?

```
    @IBAction func savetoIcloud(_ sender: Any) {
    
    NSWorkspace.shared.open(
            URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?section=Password")!,
            configuration: NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
        )
    
}
```

Comment: What version of macOS? At least under Monterey and Ventura (macOS 12.x and 13.x), Passwords is not under "Privacy and Security", it's its own tab.

Comment: I'm on Ventura, I want it to redirect me directly to the 'Passwords' tab. but the code I am using redirects me to 'Privacy and Security' instead and I'm not sure why.

Comment: It would seem to me that the `com.apple.preference.security` value is for the “Privacy and Security” tab. I’m just guessing but maybe something like `com.apple.preference.passwords` would go to the Passwords tab.